# Keep random number for x amount of time

Tags: php, random, timer

Right now I generate a random number every time a page is reloaded, I use that number to change the background image of my website.

Every page reload is a little too much, **how would I only allow the number to change every x minutes?**

Code in my header right now is really easy..

```
$randombg = rand(1,29);

echo '<style type="text/css">
<!--
#header-container{
background: url(images/header-bg' . $randombg . '.jpg) 50% 0;
}
-->
</style>';
```

Comment: Add a session variable, if time expires - create new image, update session variable.

Comment: As an alternative, you could change the background every five or ten page changes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a session variable to track time passed since last `rand` call, also you have to store a variable with bg num in a session too:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['bg_expire_time']) || $_SESSION['bg_expire_time'] < time()) {
    $_SESSION['bg'] = rand(1, 29);
    $_SESSION['bg_expire_time'] = time() + 180;  // + 3 minutes
}

echo '<style type="text/css">
<!--
#header-container{
background: url(images/header-bg' . $_SESSION['bg'] . '.jpg) 50% 0;
}
-->
</style>';
```

Of course, don't forget to start session with `session_start()`.